# How to create a maven project using Spring MVC and JPA without hibernate?

Tags: maven, jpa, tomcat, model-view-controller

I want to know  whether it is possible to create a web application using spring mvc,maven and  jpa  but without the use of Hibernate.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Ahd which JPA implementation do you want to use instead? EclipseLink, DataNucleus, OpenJPA?

Comment: Without using a implementation, we cannot  create a web project right? I'm new to jpa. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: JPA is just an API and a Specification. Hibernate is an implementation of Hibernate. You cannot use JPA without implementation

Comment: Thank You Simon  Martinelli. But if want to develop the same web application with hibernate means I need to add some additional xml for using hibernate, isn't it?

Comment: No. Why don't you start by searching on Google and you will find tons of tutorials and documentation. Like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate or you search for "spring boot book" and by one of the books

Comment: Okay I'll see to it.Thanks for your help   Simon Martinelli .